# L^1 is a Banach space with integral of the absolute value norm

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces

I have to show that if $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a complete measure space (if $E\in \mathcal{M}$ has measure $0$, then every subset is measurable and has measure $0$, then $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ with the norm $||f||_1=\int_X|f|d\mu$ is a Banach space.

So, first of all, I showed that the given norm, is indeed a norm, which is easy. But my problem begins with the completness. I know that I have to prove that the normed space is complete:

I was told by my  professor that I can use this proposition:

If $(V,||\cdot||)$ is a normed space such that for every sequence $(v_n)$ with the property: if $\sum ||v_n||<\infty$, then  $\sum v_n < \infty$; then the normed space is complete.

So let $\{f_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in  $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$, with the given property. I started with $\sum ||f_n||_1 = \sum \int_X |f_n| d\mu$. The  first thing that comes to my mind is that I should define a function and prove that  my series converges to that.

Let $\varphi_n$ be the sequence given by: $\varphi_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f_i|$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It's a monotone sequence and $\int \varphi_n = \sum \int |f_i| = \sum_{i=1}^{n} ||f||_1 < \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}||f_i||_1 $ for every n.

By the monotone convergence theorem, there exists $\varphi$ such that $lim_n \varphi_n(x) = \varphi(x)$ for almost every x,  so for almost all x the series $\sum |f_i(x)| = \varphi(x)$ converges.

Now, defining $f= \sum f_i$, it also converges, but for almost all x.

What should I do with that measure 0 set? I can define f to be any number, 0, for example, in that set? And are those the same element of $\mathcal{L}^1$?Also, I cannot figure out why or when I should use the complete measure space hypothesis. Maybe is to justify that indeed, those are the same element of $\mathcal{L}^1$.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is meant here by $\sum v_n < \infty$? Do you mean that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n v_i$ is bounded, that this limit converges, or do you mean some other statement?

Comment: I figured out a way to (maybe) solve the problem, but I was trying to say that the limit converges, just a mistype, sorry

Comment: It's all good. I just wanted to double-check that I understood the question you're asking correctly

Comment: Here you have the edited question, with some advances. Thanks for your time

Comment: What @memerson said.  So not say "$\sum v_m < \infty$" when you mean "$\sum v_m$ converges", unless $v_m$ is positive so that you know either it converges or it **diverges to infinity**.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum \int_X |f_n|d\mu <\infty$ implies $ \int_X \sum |f_n|d\mu <\infty$ by Fubini/Tonelli and this implies $\sum |f_n| <\infty$ a.e.. So $f=\sum f_n$ is well defined (:define it ot be $0$ on then null set where $\sum |f_n|$ does not converge). Conclude that $\sum f_n =f$ in $L^{1}$ norm.